# Status codes for JWT Token cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, error-handling, jwt, http-status-codes

The authentication is achieved using JWT. It is suggested to use `401` status code for all the expiry/invalidity cases of the token. But, the retry with refresh token from client-side should be done only on the 'expired' case, not on the 'invalidity' case. So, how to differ these cases with an appropriate status code? (i.e., what status code could I use for first case and what could be used for the second case?)

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend to differentiate between the cases so you can stay self-contained because there are many other cases that might cause the access token to be prohibited.

Theoretically the provider might change the implementation of the refresh token generation process so the refresh token might be valid only once the client always gets the recent refresh when fetching the access token.

If you still want to differentiate between the cases then you might add reason to response payload and build a logic to handle each reason. But this is still a security aspect that must be addressed if you want to provide reason to the user because as much information you give to the client as you are opening a door for attacks.

Answer (score 0):

- The only way to get a token is that issue a renewed JWT token.
- Even if it is expired, it is invalid so I think you have to renew token anyway.
- May be you want a retry automatically.. In some respects, it means token is useless. because your client can renew always. you'll need a detailed & specific criteria for the case.